# how to find volume of a cylindrical shell

Tags: calculus

I need to Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.

I don't know the methodology or the rules to find this and i find this question to be a bit complex. I would appreciate any help. thank you

this is the given from the question:

$y = 4/7(x^2), y=11/7-x^2$, about the $x$-axis

Comment: Integrate the difference of the two equations (using washer, shell, whatever method you're working with) with the bounds for the integral as the points where the two lines intersect

Comment: how do i get the points? @Duncan

Comment: Set the two equations equal to each other. This gives you the points where the two lines intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below graph and it should tell you what happens to the area bound by the two curves when you rotate it around x-axis.

[image]

Curve $S1$ is given by $y = \frac{4}{7}x^2$

Curve $S2$ is given by $y = \frac{11}{7} - x^2$

Equating the two, you get intersection points as $(1,\frac{4}{7}), (-1,\frac{4}{7})$.

Now when you rotate, the area of the cylindrical shell for a given $x$ will be the area  of rotation of curve $S2$ (radius being its $y$ for a given $x$) minus the area of rotation of curve $S1$ (radius being its $y$) (as you can see that for $x \in (-1,1)$, $S2$ has higher value of $y$ than $S1$).

So, desired volume $ \displaystyle = \pi \int_{-1}^{1} [y(S2)^2 - y(S1)^2] \, dx = \pi \int_{-1}^{1} [(\frac{11}{7} - x^2)^2 - (\frac{4}{7}x^2)^2] \, dx$

Can you take it from here?